# Routine software update fails on 22.04 with unresolved dependencies

Tags: updates

When running what appears to be a very routine software update (2023-08-05), it fails with this error:

"Package dependencies cannot be resolved"

This error could be caused by required additional software packages which
are missing or not installable  Furthermore there could be a conflict
between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the
same time

Transaction failed: Package dependencies cannot be resolved
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
libgl1-amber-dri: Depends: libglapi-mesa (>=23.04) but
23.0.4-Oubuntu1-22.04.1 is to be installed
       Depends: zlib1g(>=1:1.1.4) but 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu9.2 is to be installed
```

Is there any user action to be taken, or is this just an installer error that will be corrected?

So far, none of the suggested actions have had any effect on the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: Please add the output of `apt policy zlib1g` and `apt policy libglapi-mesa` to your question.